# Using Assembler in C without using placeholders

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

I've been assigned a task that's theoretically not too hard. A C variable should be changed by using Assembler code (asm). I've done this and it works, but the second part of the assignment is to do the same thing WITHOUT using placeholders (%).

I'm at a loss here and after some research I have still not found a solution. How can I access or maniplate C variables in assembler code without using placeholders to get the variable?

Here's the code with placeholders:

```
    volatile uint8_t number = 1;
    volatile uint8_t *number_pointer = &number;

    asm volatile(
        "ld r20, %a0" "\n\t"
        "lsl r20" "\n\t"
        "st %a0, r20" "\n\t"
        "breq resetten" "\n\t"
        "ret" "\n\t"

        "resetten:" "\n\t"
        "ldi r20, 1" "\n\t"
        "st %a0, r20"
          : "+e" (number_pointer)
    );
```

In short: How can I access and change "number_pointer" without using a %?
(The code doubles "number" until it is 128, then it starts with 1 again.)

Comment: If the variable to be changed is local (on the stack) you can make compiler-dependent assumptions about where the variable is located in memory relative to the stack pointer.

Comment: You are supposed to add a second `:` to introduce variables into registers (like `asm("blabla": : "a"(number_pointer));`), that'd but number_pointer in eax... however, using AT&T syntax you'd still use `%%eax` to access it. If the requirement is not using `%` (as you imply at the end), then that does not work... if the requirement is not using __placeholders__, that'd do (you'd be using a register).

Comment: How about declaring number_pointer as a static or global?  Then you could access it directly from the asm via the symbol name.  I wouldn't recommend it for production code, but for puzzle solving it should work.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! David's solution is what I did in the end. Didn't know it was so easy.

Comment: Just to emphasize: Accessing statics and globals in inline asm WITHOUT listing them as inputs or outputs can cause a number of problems.  For example, if the only references to the symbols are inside these types of asm, gcc may discard the symbols as unused.  Also (for non-volatiles), gcc may be holding an interim value in a register that it hasn't yet written to memory.  So while this "works", it's not generally a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

To comment on Davids suggestion (I would post this as comment if I had enough reputation): use the "memory" hint in the clobbered field, like in asm("nop":::"memory");

This tells gcc that the asm statement modifies memory and that variables need to be re-loaded, etc.

For example, with

```
static int foo;
int bar()
{
  foo = 1;
  __asm__("":::"memory");
  return foo;
}
```

we get

Dump of assembler code for function bar:

```
   0x0000000000000000 <+0>:         movl   $0x1,0x0(%rip)        # 0xa <bar+10>
   0x000000000000000a <+10>:        mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 0x10 <bar+16>
   0x0000000000000010 <+16>:        retq
```

whereas without the "memory", the re-load of the variable value is missing.

Comment: While this can work, it may introduce additional performance issues.  Since "memory" means that the asm can read/write ALL memory, the compiler may have to flush (and reload) more than just the one register.  Again, the better solution is to just list the variable as an input or output.

Comment: Yes, that's understood, properly using inputs and outputs is always the preferred solution. In the context of OP's question, this is explicitly not an option, so you *have* to list "memory" as clobbered if you want to write to a global variable, or to any other memory - without it, the program might be slightly faster, but it may also be incorrect, depending on how the compiler optimizes what it thinks are invariant values.